# SQL Fulltext: What items have not been indexed?

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I have a Fulltext index on one of my tables which contains some metadata and a document blob (PDF or Doc or RTF etc)

Sometimes there is an error indexing a row and therefore the row cannot be returned in Fulltext searches.

**What query could I use to find out what items have NOT been indexed?**

I thought something like this:

Select * from MyTable where MyTableID NOT IN 
(
select MyTableID from MyTable
where contains(Title, Title)
)

And then work out which rows were not returned. But the inner query is not syntactically correct and I cant work it out.

Any ideas?

Cheers
Aaron

Comment: Does anyone have anything to contribute? I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news and good news:

Bad news - There is no way to find out what items have not been indexed just by using a simple query.

Good News - You can add a datetime on your fulltext table and store the insert date for each record on it. Then, you can create a Log table that will contains the last date that a population was executed. Using this table you can find out wich records were not indexed since last index population.

I dont know if I made myself clear. I just did what i said today. I created a job that will start a population, and another job that will check if the population is done and populate the log table with the last index population date.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not solve this specific issue. Your solution helps identify the progress of a population but it would be unable to identify specific records that have not been indexed.

Comment: I am afraid its not possible at all. I have been trying to do the same thing and i had no luck so far. I guess theres no way of a record not being indexed, but I am not sure about it.